# How to hide all other divs when hovering on one div in the same group using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, hover

I have simple question for you but it's magic for me :)

I have a group DIV with similar DIVS inside like that:

```
<div id="group">

    <div class="item">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
    </div>

</div>
```

What I want to get is when I hover on one .item - I'd like to change the opacity of other .item(s) in group (#group) to 0.4 but not the one I'm hovering. Is there any simple solution for jQuery to do that if I have different amount of items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:- <kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gpY57/)</kbd>

<kbd>[See Opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/opacity)</kbd>

```
.item:not(:hover)
{
    opacity:0.4;
}
```

for IE8 and earlier add:- `filter:Alpha(opacity=40)`

See the bottom section for support <kbd>[Hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3ahover)</kbd>  <kbd>[:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anot)</kbd>

Comment: Does CSS "not(:hover)" supported by all browsers?

Comment: for IE8 and earlier, your `filter` would be irrelevant ... because it doesnt see it without a shim.

Comment: Hate IE for these things.. But traditional jquery approach would do then :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
$('.item').hover(function(){
    $('.item').not(this).css('opacity','0.4');
},function(){
    $('.item').not(this).css('opacity','1');
});
```

Or:

```
$('.item').mouseover(function(){
    $('.item').not(this).css('opacity','0.4');
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('.item').not(this).css('opacity','1');
});
```

[**Jsfiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/vsatp/)

Comment: this method of `.hover()` no longer works with the most recent version of jQuery.

Comment: guess they put it back in, it was specifically not working in 1.8 and 1.9. my bad then.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of the jquery you would need:

```
var $item = $('.item');

$item.on({
    mouseenter:function(){
        $item.not(this).css({opacity:0});
    },
    mouseleave:function(){
        $item.css({opacity:1}).removeAttr('style');
    }
});
```

And [here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KNsuQ/) for reference.

Comment: yeah i saw urs too haha. i appear to be the only guy that knows how to store a selector in cache though...

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this. Here is one:

```
$(".item").on(
    {
      mouseenter: function() 
    {
        $(".item").not(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.4);
    },
    mouseleave: function()
    {
        $(".item").fadeTo('slow', 1);
    }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H4gYf/